# Yii: User Auth thru db not working - "Null" when retrieving User model instance

Tags: database, authentication, yii

i wanna to do user auth thru db. I've created db User with some fields and inserted some records. `username=admin`, `password=admin`; `username=demo`, `password=demo`.
Now i've applied the gii to make a model '`User`' out of my table, saved the model both in **models** and in **components** folders.
In *`UserIdentity.php`* i do the model retrieval , yet the dump shows the retrieved object is **NULL**! Interesting, I've done the same retrieval in my custom controller and it rather worked!

```
  public function authenticate()
{
    /* $users=array(
        // username => password
        'demo'=>'demo',
        'admin'=>'admin',
    ); */       
    $users = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
    var_dump($users);
    // $username=strtolower($this->username);
    // $users=User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array($username));

    if(!isset($users[$this->username]))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif($users[$this->username]->password !== $this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

What's wrong, do i need to mention this User model/component in main.php attribute 'user' configuration? and how?
Also, the User class obviously extends the CActiveRecord, rather then CWebUser. Is it normal?

```
 class User extends CActiveRecord
 {

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'user';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('username, password, created', 'required'),
        array('role, ban', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('username, password', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, username, password, created, role, ban', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'username' => 'Name',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'created' => 'Created',
        'role' => 'Role',
        'ban' => 'Ban',
    );
}

public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
    $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
    $criteria->compare('created',$this->created,true);
    $criteria->compare('role',$this->role);
    $criteria->compare('ban',$this->ban);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

The problem is that, when I try to login with this kind of db plugging (sure without dump line), I get always **Incorrect username or password**.

**LoginForm.php**:

```
private $_identity;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // username and password are required
        array('username, password', 'required'),
        // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
        array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
        // password needs to be authenticated
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
    );
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'rememberMe'=>'Remember me next time',
    );
}
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
    }
}
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
  }
 }
```

Here is the code from in the other controller for dumping 'admin' record from the model `User`:

```
$username = 'admin';
    $users = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$username));
    foreach ($users->attributes as $key=>$value){
            echo  $key . ' => '. $value. '</br>';
         } 
    Yii::app()->end();
```

the result is excellent:

```
id => 1
username => admin
password => admin
created => 2013-08-16 00:00:00
role => 1
ban => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the following section:

```
if(!isset($users[$this->username]))
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
elseif($users[$this->username]->password !== $this->password)
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
else
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
return !$this->errorCode;
```

Try changing that to:

```
if($users == null))
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
elseif($users->password !== $this->password)
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
else
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
return !$this->errorCode;
```

The `$users` variable is an object and cannot be used as an array (`$users[$this->username]`) as was possible in the original script where the `$users` array contained the login information. When you changed it to authenticate through the db, the variable now contains the db row corresponding to the username entered in the login form (if any)...

Comment: it didn't help. Since `$users` is already **Null** thru `var_dump($users);`, so the 'Incorrect username or password.' remains.
But thank you for this correction.

Comment: You say you saved the **User.php** model file in both components and models directory? If so it should only be present in the models directory. Delete the one in the components directory. Maybe the wrong file is getting included in your authenticate() function because of this... Just guessing.

Comment: no avail. now it's only in **models** folder. But is there (should there be) any relation between the **User** and **CWebUser** classes?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your LoginForm.php model file (it should be in the models directory). That is where the authenticate() function actually gets called.

Comment: i've posted, no changes (to the original yii file) have been done though.

Comment: Everything seems to be in order... What you have should work. The only other thing i can think of is to double check the values as well as cases (lower v/s upper) in the database and var_dump the value of the $this->username in the authenticate() function...

Comment: Fijas, thank you very much!!!
It turned that your answer was right, but even when i changed the code for your, it did not work cause i kept the former `demo/demo` auth pair that was not stored in db.

Comment: I've a sub question. 
**How to create new users with hashed passwords stored in db?**

Now i want to create new users, but i need to store passwords encoded. Should i do it thru gii generated CRUD functionality or somehow else? Since i cannot manually produce and store hashes in db.

Comment: The short answer is that you have to enter the hashed (sha1 for eg.) form of the password in the db and then while comparing in the authenticate() method, you have to check for `$users->password !== sha1($this->password)`. For more details I would suggest you visit the following link: [db based authentication](http://hungred.com/how-to/customize-authentication-yii-framework-mysql-database/)